# Binary Search Tree forces me to input 0 with my numbers

Tags: java

I am not sure to why the program forces in a "0" into the tree and sorts it along with the other inputted numbers. It requires an input in the constructor and I don't want it to require an input.

Also, how do I check for duplicates when the user inputs one line of integers like "1 2 3 2 4"? How do you remove a specific int from the line of integers?

Every time the user inputs some number(s), I just end up with the "0" attached to my set of numbers.

Constructor:

```
public BinarySearchTree(int num) {  
    this.data = num;    
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}
```

addNode:

```
        public void addNode(int num) {

        if (num < this.data) {
            if (this.left != null) {
                this.left.addNode(num);
            }       else {
                this.left = new BinarySearchTree(num);
            }

}       else {
        if (this.right != null) {
            this.right.addNode(num);
}       else {
            this.right = new BinarySearchTree(num);
}

}
}
```

I have `traversePreOrder`, `traversePost`, and `traverseIn`:

```
public void traversePreOrder() {
    System.out.print( this.data + " ");
    if( this.left != null ) {
        this.left.traversePreOrder();
    }
    if( this.right != null ) {
        this.right.traversePreOrder();
    }
}
public void traverseInOrder() {
    if( this.left != null ) {
        this.left.traverseInOrder();
    }
        System.out.print( this.data + " ");
    if( this.right != null ) {
        this.right.traverseInOrder();
    }

public void traversePostOrder() {
    if( this.left != null ) {
        this.left.traversePostOrder();
    }   
    if( this.right != null ) {
        this.right.traversePostOrder();
    }
        System.out.print( this.data + " ");
    }
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean duplicates = false,done = false;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);` 

    BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree( 0 );
    System.out.println("Please enter values: " );
    String[] input = keyboard.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
    for(String values: input)
        tree.addNode(Integer.parseInt(values));
```

Expected:
Pre-order: 1

Actual: 
Pre-order: 0 1 //always places a 0

Comment: The "BinarySearchTree" class you show evidently defines a node in the tree, and every such node has a data value. You can't construct a node without it.   The first node you insert becomes the root, and it your case, that's the node whose value is zero.  Who defined this class?

Comment: "why the program forces..." -> because it is coded that way, so you have to ask the author why he programmed it that way. She/he could have read the first value and used it instead of `0` to create the tree.

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is used to initialize the class. You need to modify your constructor. When you write `BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree( 0 );`  it is also inserting the value '0' into your binary search tree. Since 0 is also part of the tree, you are seeing 0 along with the other numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Constructor` you are expecting an `int num` and if you don't provide it in your `main` class, it'll through an error. So, what you have to do is to define a `no argument Constructor` explicitly like this:

```
public BinarySeacrhTree(){}
```

Now in your main class create object like this:

```
  BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
```

Now, coming to duplication issue, in my point of view don't bother how many duplicates user inputs your `addNode()` should take care of it.

> If value is smaller than `currentNode` insert on left.
>
> If value is greater than `currentNode` insert on right.
>
> If value is equal to `currentNode` do nothing.

Third point is taking care of what you are asking. If you need some other help o who to achieve it just ask, I am here to help.

**UPDATE:**
Following code will clear all your confusions, I deliberately added duplicate value:

```
class TreeNode
{
    TreeNode leftNode;
    TreeNode rightNode;
    int data;
    
    public TreeNode(int nodeData)
    {
        data = nodeData;
        leftNode = rightNode = null;
    }
    
    public void insert(int insertValue)
    {
        if(insertValue < data)
        {
            if(leftNode == null)
                leftNode = new TreeNode(insertValue);
            else
                leftNode.insert(insertValue);
        }
        else if(insertValue > data)
        {
            if(rightNode == null)
                rightNode = new TreeNode(insertValue);
            else
                rightNode.insert(insertValue);
        }
        else{}   // if duplicate then do nothing

    }
}

class Tree
{
    public TreeNode root;
    public Tree()
    {
        root = null;
    }
    
    public void insertNode(int insertValue)
    {
        if(root == null)
            root = new TreeNode(insertValue);
        else
            root.insert(insertValue);
    }
    
    public void preOrder()
    {
        preorder(root);
    }
    
    public void preorder(TreeNode node)
    {
        if(node == null)
            return;
        System.out.printf(" %s",node.data);
        preorder(node.leftNode);
        preorder(node.rightNode);
    }
    
    public void inOrder()
    {
        inorder(root);
    }
    
    public void inorder(TreeNode node)
    {
        if(node == null)
            return;
    
        inorder(node.leftNode);
        System.out.printf(" %s",node.data);
        inorder(node.rightNode);
    }
    
    public void postOrder()
    {
        postorder(root);
    }
    
    public void postorder(TreeNode node)
    {
        if(node == null)
            return;
        
        postorder(node.leftNode);
        postorder(node.rightNode);
        System.out.printf(" %s",node.data);
    }   
}

public class stackMainTree
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Tree tree = new Tree();
        tree.insertNode(1);
        tree.insertNode(8);
        tree.insertNode(7);
        tree.insertNode(5);
        tree.insertNode(13);
        tree.insertNode(13);
        
        tree.inOrder();
    }
}
```

Now, test and try to understand how you were handling and how it should be handled and make most out of OOP.

Comment: but i need to include an input for the BinarySearchTree(int num) because i need to use this in the future methods... is there a way i can change the methods so that they don't get errors when I change  to BinarySearchTree()?

Comment: Yes of course but for this i'll have to see those methods too of which you are talking about.

Comment: Your modifications should work... Place `addNode()` method in your question. I think I have to change that a bit, these printing methods don't need any changing.

Comment: It still doesn't work. When I user input "1", it outputs "0 0" for each traverse for some reason... I think it's because the data isn't being referenced back into the methods so none of them have any data to work with ....

Comment: Your approach is bit wrong that's why all this is happening. What do you want your code to do ? Tell me and I'll edit my answer accordingly. But be quick in replying to this comment.

Comment: The issue is in your `addNode()` thats I am sure of.

Comment: The code worked before I changed it to have no input and now it doesn’t work. The issue isn’t addNode because I didn’t even call this method for the traverses. Basically, when I modify it to satisfy the BinarySearchTree() (with no input) it doesn’t work the way it used to. It was working just fine when sorting (just includes the random 0) and then now it doesn’t work at all.

Comment: When you make it BinarySearchTree() (with no input), then what doesn't work are the traverses methods ? If yes ten what error do they give ?

Comment: There are no errors. The user input data just isn’t getting linked into the tree anymore. The methods I believe are working just fine because they worked perfectly before I ever did anything.

Comment: See, in `addNode` you are again using ` new BinarySearchTree(num);` when you don't have a constructor that takes an `int` as a parameter.

Comment: I used it because it worked just fine except for the random 0. When i remove all the “num”, it outputs a bunch of zeros aka it’s not working with data anymore and I’m not sure why.

Comment: Looking into it, wait a while.

Comment: okay thanks for the help :) sorry if i was being confusing on relaying the issue i’m encountering with the code. i’m actually pretty new to java so i apologize if i make any false statements.

Comment: See, you have to make `Tree` class and `TreeNode` class separately. This is the right way to do. Tree is something different and Node is different. The issue starts when you are doing everything in `Tree` setting node data and next, previous nodes.

Comment: so what would i put in tree vs treenode?

Comment: Watch my edit to the answer you can change methods and variables name as per your wish later.

Comment: Updated the answer, if you find any difficult i am here to help, but if you found your answer then kindly do mark it "answer" and "upvote" :)

Comment: Did it work for you ? Just curious to know whether my time and effort payed off or not !

Comment: I don't see your updated answer could u please try again?

Comment: I have updated it, I can see how come you don't? try refreshing your web age.

Comment: nevermind i see it, i will test it when i get the chance thanks!

Comment: it doesn't work in that it just runs my original code

Comment: @AshleyYu New users must take this to account, that if they find the answer correct and it resolves their issue, then kindly mark that as answer. so that if someone have the same issue in future they can get a handy help without asking a new question. That's how things work here . Welcome to SO :)